# 'javac' is not recognized and rmiregistry is not found

Tags: java, batch-file, rmi, javac, path-variables

Im trying to run a simple RMI application via batch file.
I have been given these lines by my instructor to write in notepad and save it as .bat :

1. @cd %cd%\src
2. @for /r %%a in (*.java) do @javac %%a
3. @start rmiregistry 3000
4. @java Server
5. @pause

When I run the batch files it shows that 'javac is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file', and for the RMI it shows 'The system cannot find the file rmiregistry'.

I searched for solutions for 'javac' problem and it appears I have to set a path for it in the 'Environment Variables' which I did via adding a new USER variable in the name of JAVA_HOME and the path : 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin'

The problem is consistent and I don't know where to start to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You should append this `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the `PATH` environment variable. This will solve your problem.

OR Alternatively,

you should directly add this directory location to the end of the PATH environment variable.

```
PATH=........;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
 // here ....... denotes previous entry done already in PATH
```

Or, SET Path by typing the following in the CMD(console/command prompt) as :-

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
```

Comment: I must say I am very confused by this "PATH" environment subject. Where can I find this PATH environment variable? and how to append it ?
I did not understand how to do the first two steps but I did the third one with the cmd but nothing changed. I add JAVA_HOME to systems variables but the problem is still there.
Maybe you have a step by step guide on how to do it ? thanks

Comment: @MajdKharman- Check this [page](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) OR you should alternatively perform only the last line of this answer and reboot your system. It will help surely.

Comment: I set the path accordingly but now it shows me another problem :
**javac: invalid flag : C\Users\majd\Documents\Eclipse
Usage : javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options**
and this message repeats 4 times, meaning for the 4 classes I have in project.
at the end it writes : 
**Error : Could find or load main class Server**
I think I have a problem in the lines written in the batch file/notepad. 
The RMI registry window opens up though.
Any help ? I will vote and accept the answer when I solve this problem :)

Comment: @MajdKharman You need to double-check that you have transcribed the 'for' line correctly.